# How to debug PostgreSQL segmentation fault?

Tags: debian, postgresql, segmentation-fault

I have a PostgreSQL 13 instance that keeps crashing:

```
LOG:  server process (PID 10722) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
DETAIL:  Failed process was running: COMMIT
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

I've updated `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_ctl.conf` to include core dumps

```
pg_ctl_options = '--core-files'
```

and restarted `postgresql` service. Now it seems to allow core dumps:

```
$ for f in `pgrep postgres`; do cat /proc/$f/limits | grep core; done
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
```

`gdb` backtrace gives following output

```
$ gdb /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/postgres 13/main/core.postgres.12264

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  slot_deform_heap_tuple (natts=5, offp=0x557cc2e60720, tuple=<optimized out>, slot=0x557cc2e606d8) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execTuples.c:930
930     ./build/../src/backend/executor/execTuples.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  slot_deform_heap_tuple (natts=5, offp=0x557cc2e60720, tuple=<optimized out>, slot=0x557cc2e606d8) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execTuples.c:930
#1  tts_buffer_heap_getsomeattrs (slot=0x557cc2e606d8, natts=5) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execTuples.c:695
#2  0x0000557cc1d3998c in slot_getsomeattrs_int (slot=slot@entry=0x557cc2e606d8, attnum=5) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execTuples.c:1912
#3  0x0000557cc1d28fba in slot_getsomeattrs (attnum=<optimized out>, slot=0x557cc2e606d8) at ./build/../src/include/executor/tuptable.h:344
#4  ExecInterpExpr (state=0x557cc2e620a8, econtext=0x557cc2ea1768, isnull=<optimized out>) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execExprInterp.c:482
#5  0x0000557cc1d5548d in ExecEvalExprSwitchContext (isNull=0x7ffdd2599507, econtext=0x557cc2ea1768, state=0x557cc2e620a8) at ./build/../src/include/executor/executor.h:322
#6  ExecQual (econtext=0x557cc2ea1768, state=0x557cc2e620a8) at ./build/../src/include/executor/executor.h:391
#7  MJFillInner (node=0x557cc2ea1558) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/nodeMergejoin.c:494
#8  0x0000557cc1d55ce8 in ExecMergeJoin (pstate=0x557cc2ea1558) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/nodeMergejoin.c:1353
#9  0x0000557cc1d2cc83 in ExecProcNode (node=0x557cc2ea1558) at ./build/../src/include/executor/executor.h:248
#10 ExecutePlan (execute_once=<optimized out>, dest=0x557cc2e1a630, direction=<optimized out>, numberTuples=0, sendTuples=<optimized out>, operation=CMD_SELECT, use_parallel_mode=<optimized out>, planstate=0x557cc2ea1558, 
    estate=0x557cc2ea12f8) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execMain.c:1632
#11 standard_ExecutorRun (queryDesc=0x557cc2e1a5a0, direction=<optimized out>, count=0, execute_once=<optimized out>) at ./build/../src/backend/executor/execMain.c:350
#12 0x00007f0ec05ae09d in pgss_ExecutorRun (queryDesc=0x557cc2e1a5a0, direction=ForwardScanDirection, count=0, execute_once=<optimized out>) at ./build/../contrib/pg_stat_statements/pg_stat_statements.c:1045
#13 0x0000557cc1cdbcd4 in PersistHoldablePortal (portal=portal@entry=0x557cc2d44b78) at ./build/../src/backend/commands/portalcmds.c:407
#14 0x0000557cc1ff95f9 in HoldPortal (portal=portal@entry=0x557cc2d44b78) at ./build/../src/backend/utils/mmgr/portalmem.c:642
#15 0x0000557cc1ff9e7d in PreCommit_Portals (isPrepare=isPrepare@entry=false) at ./build/../src/backend/utils/mmgr/portalmem.c:738
#16 0x0000557cc1c001c4 in CommitTransaction () at ./build/../src/backend/access/transam/xact.c:2087
#17 0x0000557cc1c015d5 in CommitTransactionCommand () at ./build/../src/backend/access/transam/xact.c:3085
#18 0x0000557cc1ea211d in finish_xact_command () at ./build/../src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:2662
#19 0x0000557cc1ea4703 in exec_simple_query (query_string=0x557cc2c9cd28 "COMMIT") at ./build/../src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:1264
#20 0x0000557cc1ea6143 in PostgresMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=argv@entry=0x557cc2cf6c68, dbname=<optimized out>, username=<optimized out>) at ./build/../src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:4339
#21 0x0000557cc1e25bcd in BackendRun (port=0x557cc2ce94d0, port=0x557cc2ce94d0) at ./build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4526
#22 BackendStartup (port=0x557cc2ce94d0) at ./build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4210
#23 ServerLoop () at ./build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1739
#24 0x0000557cc1e26b41 in PostmasterMain (argc=5, argv=<optimized out>) at ./build/../src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1412
#25 0x0000557cc1b70f4f in main (argc=5, argv=0x557cc2c96c30) at ./build/../src/backend/main/main.c:210
```

Adding `log_statement = 'all'` to `/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` doesn't really help, as `postmaster` terminates all processes immediately and the query doesn't get written to logs.

here's `strace` output after running `COMMIT`

```
[pid 20006] pwrite64(29, "COMMIT", 6, 15936) = 6
[pid 20006] pwrite64(29, "\0", 1, 15942) = 1
[pid 20006] close(29)                   = 0
[pid 20006] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x10} ---
[pid 20006] +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
<... select resumed> )                  = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_DUMPED, si_pid=20006, si_uid=108, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV && WCOREDUMP(s)}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 20006
write(2, "2021-09-08 13:38:51.853 UTC [299"..., 198) = 198
write(2, "2021-09-08 13:38:51.853 UTC [299"..., 88) = 88
kill(19324, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19324, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19331, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19331, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19320, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19320, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19319, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19319, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19321, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19321, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19322, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19322, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
kill(19323, SIGQUIT)                    = 0
kill(-19323, SIGQUIT)                   = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7ffe90814374, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE SEGV CONT SYS RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
select(7, [5 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=5, tv_usec=0}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19320, si_uid=108, si_status=2, si_utime=14, si_stime=3} ---
```

Is there a way how to trace back the exact SQL query that was executed?

Comment: If it keeps happening at the same spot, you most likely have encountered some sort of bug and should be filing a bug report.

Comment: In addition to the above, have you looked at the logs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I'll try to do that, in the meantime I need to find some workaround in order to avoid crashing whole postgres

Comment: @NasirRiley There's nothing interesting in the logs except the lines already shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly install debugging symbols for your distribution, for Debian distros:

```
apt install gdb postgresql-13-dbgsym
```

Jump to a frame that contains some `queryDesc` variable, e.g `12`:

```
(gdb) frame 12
#12 0x00007f0ec05ae09d in pgss_ExecutorRun (queryDesc=0x557cc302b7d0, direction=ForwardScanDirection, count=0, execute_once=<optimized out>) at ./build/../contrib/pg_stat_statements/pg_stat_statements.c:1045
1045    in ./build/../contrib/pg_stat_statements/pg_stat_statements.c
```

print that variable:

```
(gdb) p queryDesc
$1 = (QueryDesc *) 0x557cc302b7d0
```

now copy the line above after equal sign and dereference it using `*`

```
(gdb) p *(QueryDesc *) 0x557cc302b7d0
$6 = {operation = CMD_SELECT, plannedstmt = 0x557cc300e218, 
  sourceText = 0x557cc302b370 "\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "DECLARE \"categoryPagePhotoUrl_image_urls\" CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "SELECT di.itemId, image_number, filename FROM (SELECT *\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "FROM downl"..., snapshot = 0x557cc2e9b188, crosscheck_snapshot = 0x0, dest = 0x557cc302b860, params = 0x0, queryEnv = 0x0, instrument_options = 0, tupDesc = 0x557cc2f7bff8, 
  estate = 0x557cc2cf8d08, planstate = 0x557cc2cf8f68, already_executed = true, totaltime = 0x0}
```

It doesn't give you the whole query but at least an idea on which table is the query executed.

Based on the `gdb` output I've managed to isolate clients that were executing such query.

I've tried running `VACUUM FULL` on the affected table, rebuilding table and indexes, switching to replica, copying whole database using `pg_dump`. Nonetheless the issue still persisted also on database copies.

Finally I've managed to isolate a [minimal SQL code to replicate the issue](https://gist.github.com/deric/b3e82a8ace7fb92935984c2f30361f5c).

```
$ pg_createcluster 13 main
$ createdb testdb
$ psql -d testdb -f postgresql-segfault.sql
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE TABLE
COPY 1
ALTER TABLE
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
DECLARE CURSOR
 itemid  
---------
 1190300
(1 row)

psql:postgresql-segfault:34: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
psql:postgresql-segfault:34: fatal: connection to server was lost
```

With a code to replicate this was enough to [report a bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAPV2KRjd%3DErgVGbvO2Ty20tKTEZZr6cYsYLxgN_W3eAo9pf5sw%40mail.gmail.com) to [pgsql-bugs](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-bugs/) mailing list (there's also a webform). Turned out to be a bug with re-execution of a plan that already reached completion on a un-stable cursor that [was included in PostgreSQL](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=c1fd756fd23f60fcac120c9cd36de2921144e3bd) 13.4, 12.8 (and possibly other versions).

Comment: You saved me a lot of trouble debugging this one, thank you.